# How does ASP.NET MVC encourage parallel development?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what is parallel development and how it supports parallel development in MVC?

Answer (score 2):

It is right there where you read it, in [ASP.NET MVC Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx):

> The loose coupling between the three main components of an MVC application also promotes parallel development. **For example, one developer can work on the view, a second developer can work on the controller logic, and a third developer can focus on the business logic in the model.**

As opposed to a PHP or ASPX file where you can have business logic, data access and presentation logic in one file.

You could of course do the same in a view, but you really shouldn't. It's the pattern of MVC that encourages the separation of concerns.